# Printing range of number upward or backward according to users first input

Tags: c, printing, integer

I'm trying to print a range of integers (all the positive integers that to be found between the user's 2 input integers) and I need to do it by the order the user typed it.
for example:

for the input: 4,9 output would be: 4 5 6 7 8 9

and for the input: 9,4 the output would be: 9 8 7 6 5 4

I'm not allowed to use any array/strings/functions, just basic C commands.
Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Last I checked, `if` is a basic C command.

Comment: `if`, `while` or `for`, `=`, `<`, etc.  There's some hints.

Comment: The only person whose ideas are relevant here is you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is most likely a learning exercise, here are some points to think about:

- You need a loop.
- The loop starts at the first number the user enters, and ends upon reaching the second number
- The step of the loop depends on the order of the numbers entered by the user
- If the first number is smaller than the second one, the step of the loop is one
- If the first number is larger than the second one, the step of the loop is negative one

Therefore, the structure of your program is going to be as follows:

- Prompt the user for the two numbers
- Read numbers one and two
- Compute the step using an `if`
- Print out the range using a loop (`for`, `while`, or `do`/`while`, it's up to you).

This should be enough to complete your assignment. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to do with 1 loop? I can tell that I need to scan with an index from the start to the end using a loop, but my question is this: is it possible to do with just one loop for both cases?

Comment: @user3921 Absolutely - you need a single loop. Once you know the step, 1 or -1, you can do `current += step` in your loop, which will advance `current` up or down, depending on the direction that the user has chosen. You need an `if` to compute the value of the `step`.